# a stackoverflow-like website about robotics

Tags: discussion, area-51, meta, site-proposal

Seems like the number of expert-answering community websites is flourishing. I just noticed the existance of [chiphacker](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/). Everything very interesting around here. Thus my question is:

- what about something on Robotics?

Rationale: I'm currently working on a robotics project myself (the iCub), which involves lots of coding (either embedded and c/c++; so something that should be discussed on stackoverflow), hardware issues (chiphacker), system issues (a-la serverfault), so on and so forth and some added spices such as svn problems, versioning (superuser.com?), wiki, naming issues, etc.

Plus, the robotics community usually gets lost around re-inventing the wheel (in terms of algorithms, frameworks, etc). You have no idea how much code is lost and re-coded, and the poor comments are just lost in the midst.

Furthermore, I think it would be cool to take the robotics folks out of academia and into the real world. Just a bit, you know, so that we can be ready for when the bots will take over and rule the world :)

If the idea is accepted we need a name..

Answer (score 4):

Bit late, but I stumbled on this question looking for a SO for robotics.

Just wanted to add, there seems to be one here at https://robotics.stackexchange.com/ and it appears to be active.

Answer (score 2):

found [one here](http://roboticsxchange.com/)

also somebody asked my same question a few seconds later. Must be the trend.

Comment: Good find! Crazy horrible colour scheme though.

Comment: That other question - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2582/robooverflow has been around for a while (4 months), it was just updated today.

Comment: Unfortunately, as of May 2011, the http://roboticsxchange.com/ does not seem to exist anymore